# Raspberry PI 3B+ SSH troubleshooting

Tags: ssh

I am trying to SSH into a RPI 3B+ using a mac. I have etched the Raspbian Buster(Feb 2020)full image onto a micro SD card and also have added the "ssh" and "wpa_supplicant.conf" files into the "boot" partition which was created. But after putting the the card into the RPi lot and turning the power on, the RPi is not connecting to my network (Mobile Hotspot). I've checked using Lanscan and have also checked the "Connected Devices" section of my phone. I can't seem to find out what the problem is.

Can someone please help me out?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you put any text in those files?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just use real vnc?https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/raspberrypi/

I've used this and it works great. Also, this seems to be a duplicate to this:
[SSH to RPI using android hotspot and PC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32628/ssh-to-rpi-using-android-hotspot-and-pc)

Look at here, and see if it gives you any hints. Is you mac also connected to the hotspot?

Comment: Don't ask questions in an answer.

Answer (score -1):

It is working now. I have added the following lines to my wpa_supplicant.conf file:

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
```

change the country code to your own country.

Comment: What does work with these lines? What is the complete content of `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`?

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.